# How to execute raw queries using GreenDAO

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, greendao

I'm starting with and thinking of integrating GreenDAO in my app but the app heavily relies on queries like this:

```
"SELECT c.Id, c.primary_name, case when c.alt_name in('','null',null) then c.primary_name else c.alt_name end alt_name,(select x.url from resource x where x.ref_id = c.id and flag ='value') url from table"
```

how do I run queries like above in GreenDAO?

Comment: `SELECT  ..., (select x.url from resource x where x.ref_id = c.id and flag ='value') url ... FROM ...` do you know that we have `JOIN` in SQL ? ... and `case ...then` can be easily moved to model

Comment: @Selvin i know there are joins just giving an example. The question is how to run it in GreenDAO?